# JavaScript not changing DOM in my HTML Template after load in Apps Script

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

[image: Why My Second Line Targeting div id="load1" is not executing]

I am trying to build a simple dashboard where if user access their dashboard it will show data from the google spreadsheet. But There is one problem I don't know why only my first div is getting target via JavaScript not the second one..

any Help and solution would apricated..

Why My Second Line Targeting div id="load1" is not executing ????

Code.gs

```
`function loadDetails(id){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("14RM_170AefKbQq82NXAdSOemQLyAGcv_BTwYWd1-qtM")
   var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data")
   var data = ws.getDataRange().getValues()
     for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
         var row = data[i]
        if(row[0]== id){
           password = {
             psd: row[1],
             id: row[0]
            }
         }
      }
      if(row[0]!= id){
          password = "not found"
    }
      return password;
 }`
```

Dashboard.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  </head>

<body>
   <h1>Hey this is other Employee Dashboard</h1>
   <p>Your Employee Id: = </p>
   <p>Your Password : = </P>
   <div id="load">
   <div>
   <div id="load1">
   <div>

<script>
     window.onload = function(){
        var id = "MN00018"
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(output){
        document.getElementById("load").innerHTML = `passing objects are ${output.psd} & ${output.id}`
        document.getElementById("load1").innerHTML = `passing objects are ${output.id}`
    }).loadDetails(id)
   }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ``document.getElementById("load").innerHTML = `passing objects are ${output.id}`` is ``document.getElementById("load1").innerHTML = `passing objects are ${output.id}``?

Comment: @Tanaike review it again...

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed 2 modification points in your script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually testing your showing script, I think that there are 2 modification points.

#### HTML & Javascript side:

The tag of `div` is not enclosed. How about modifying as follows?

##### From:

```
<div id="load">
<div>
<div id="load1">
<div>
```

##### To:

```
<div id="load">
</div>
<div id="load1">
</div>
```

- I think that this is the reason of your issue of `Why My Second Line Targeting div id="load1" is not executing ????`.

#### Google Apps Script side:

At Google Apps Script side, by `if(row[0]!= id){password = "not found"}`, even when `id` is found from the column "A", "not found" is returned. How about modifying as follows?

##### Modified script:

```
function loadDetails(id) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("###");
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data")
  var data = ws.getDataRange().getValues()
  var password = {psd: "", id: ""};
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i]
    if (row[0] == id) {
      password = {
        psd: row[1],
        id: row[0]
      }
      break;
    }
  }
  return password;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply! that was really stupid me i should write server side in vs code instead of manually typing to avoid this silly mistake i guess...btw yeah it's now working i need to set interval also because now script shoot at once....thanks again..

Comment: @Kuldeep Singh Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand whether your issue was resolved. Can I ask you about it? If your issue was not resolved, I have to apologize.